# Modularization Android Kotlin - using layouts from another module

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, modularization

I have 2 modules where one of them implements another. 
In both of them I can use same layouts and methods like

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

what works like a charm (I have connectivity between them).

But when I call 
`text_view.setText = "My text"`

it gives me Unresolved reference error. On all modules I am extending kotlin-extensions and so on. Tried invalidate caches, clean, rebuilding. But when I am using `findViewById(R.id.text_view)` also works like a charm but this is not an idea of kotlin :)

Looking for ideas,
Greetings :)

@EDIT
`text_view` is of course TextView inside `activity_main`

@EDIT2
I've tried ViewBinding but it return me the same error: Unresolved reference. I checked dependencies, implementations in build.gradle. No ideas how to solve it. Copying all the same layouts to 2nd module seems to be incorrect

Comment: Kotlin Synthetics won't work across modules, but you can use ViewBinding instead introduced in AS 3.6

Comment: Oh thats valuable tip . Didn't know that korlin sythetics won't work across modules